# How to print integers in padded hexadecimal form?

Tags: output-formatting, output

I have a bunch of numbers that I want to print in hexadecimal form using exactly 16 symbols, padded left with zeros if needed. For example, if $x=255$, I want to get $f[x]="00000000000000FF"$ or $f[x]="0x00000000000000FF"$. I tried BaseForm and NumberForm but didn't quite get it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to do that without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I didn't think about IntegerString, thanks!

Comment: How do I mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 4):

```
"Ox" <> IntegerString[255, 16, 32]
```

> "Ox000000000000000000000000000000ff"

Comment: I can't find a duplicate of the question, so I propose an answer. If someone find a duplicate, inform me.